# Bash: How to implement sequential checking of multiple case-switch blocks?

Tags: bash, switch-statement

I want the first case-switch block to evaluate the 1st AND 3rd positional arguments. If the 1st provided positional arg  is not defined, then I want to move to the next case-switch block to evaluate ONLY the 3rd positional arg.

my code looks like this:

```
case "$1" in
    X)   case "$3" in
            -d) if [[ "$4" =~ ^[A-Z]+-[0-9]+$ ]]; then
                        CreateMarketDir;
                        SymlinkMarketData;
                    else
                        CreateMarketDir;
                    fi;;
         esac
    *)   echo "Exiting the first Case Block"
         exit;;
esac

case "$3" in
     -c) if [[ "$4" =~ ^[A-Z]+-[0-9]+$ ]]; then
             CreateDCDir;
             SymlinkDCData;
         else
             CreateDCDir;
         fi;;
      *) echo "Please use a valid argument"
          exit;;
esac
```

However, only the first case-switch block works - for example, the following runs OK:

```
./script.sh X foo -d
```

But when I try to run with the following args:

```
./script.sh foo bar -c
```

I get this output:

```
Please use a valid argument
```

What I assume is that if the 1st positional arg is not `X`, then the script should check the next case-switch block and evaluate the 3rd positional arg. But apparently, this is not the case.

How should I implement the sequential checking of multiple case-switch blocks?

Thank you

Comment: You have a missing quote on the `Please use a valid argument` line.

Comment: You're missing some `;;` terminators for the cases. Please post the actual code, it's impossible to tell what you did wrong when you've copied it wrong and left out so much.

Comment: Your assumption is correct, so you've done something wrong.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the feedback, I replaced the pseudo code with the actual code

Comment: You're missing `;;` after the first `esac`

Comment: Paste your script into shellcheck.net.

Comment: @Barmar indeed the missing ;; was the problem. I added it after the first esac and pasted it into shellcheck and no issues were found. However, when I run the script, now the output is "Exiting the first Case block". It looks like the script exits the first case block and does not resume to check the next one

Comment: That's because of the `exit` command. It terminates the whole script.

Answer (score -1):

As correctly pointed out by @Barmar, the issue was that the first `esac` was missing `;;` 
Also, if the script is supposed to go through separate Case-Switch blocks sequentially, then the `exit;;` must be removed from the first Case block, otherwise the whole script will be stopped